# Does cygwin32 or cygwin64 gcc support asan now?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

When the option `-fsanitize=address` is used with gcc, there are some linking errors that no asan lib found. Here is the gcc version info.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/10/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86/src/gcc-10.2.0/configure --srcdir=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86/src/gcc-10.2.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: Doesn't that already answer this question?: `there are some linking errors that no asan lib found`

Answer (score 1):

No, as you can see from [libsanitizer/configure.tgt](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libsanitizer/configure.tgt) Cygwin is not in the list of targets for which libasan is available.